# Is it possible, on an individual level, that someones fluid intelligence can "spike" in ones early twenties?

Tags: intelligence, iq, brain-development

I think IQ and fluid intelligence are interrelated enough that I can use them interchangeably. I was wondering if on an individual level, if it was possible that ones IQ can jump a certain amount of points in their early twenties? I know this is not the "general" trend at a group level, but I was just wondering if it was biologically possible since we know the brain is still developing in ones early twenties.

Thanks.

Comment: I think I saw something like that reported (in few/select individuals, who had some kind of late development), but can't find the paper right now.

Comment: If you find the paper please do get back to me, this would be most useful information.